# How can I use NSPredicate to filter on core data relationships?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, iphone

Say I have core data objects of type "obj" that has a property "propertyA" and a one-to-many relationship with an object of type "sub" that has two properties, "propertyB" and "propertyC".

I want to fetch all the objs that have propertyA equal to a value and a sub obj with propertyB and propertyC set.

If it was just propertyA and propertyB, I would do

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY sub.propertyB = %@ AND propertyA == %@", ...];
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to add in the second property. I want only the objs that have at least one sub that has the two properties true. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY (sub.propertyB = %@ AND sub.propertyC) AND propertyA == %@", ...];
```

I've tried it without the ANY but that doesn't work either. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have a to-many relationship with the sub object, the `subs` property of `obj` returns a set instead of a single object. To query the set, you need to use a SUBQUERY.

Subqueries have the form:

```
SUBQUERY(collection, $individualCollectionItem, expression-with-collection-item)
```

in this case you would want something like

```
SUBQUERY(subs,$s,$s.propertyB==%@) AND SUBQUERY(subs,$s,$s.propertyC!=NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find anything about SUBQUERYs in any of the apple documentation. Is my app going to be rejected from the apple store if I use it?

Comment: I can't get SUBQUERY to work at all. My original predicated was:

Comment: NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isdeleted == NO AND ANY appuserMessages.recAppUserID == %@",  appuserid];

Comment: appuserMessages is the to-many relationship. I wanted to isTrash, so I tried:

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isdeleted == NO AND ANY SUBQUERY(appuserMessages, $am, $am.recAppUserID == %@ AND $am.isTrash == NO)",  appuserid]; but I get "Unable to parse format string". I haven't gotten any predicate with SUBQUERY to parse at all/

Comment: I might have it. This seems to work: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isdeleted == NO AND (SUBQUERY(appuserMessages, $am, $am.recAppUserID == %@ AND $am.isTrash == NO).@count != 0)",  appuserid];

Comment: Subqueries are documented but just barely. They are perfectly legal. You can't use ANY with them because they return a set.

Comment: See [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:] for SUBQUERY documentation

Answer (score 4):

The solution seems to be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyA == %@ AND (SUBQUERY(sub, $s, $s.propertyB == %@ AND $s.propertyC == %@).@count != 0)",  propertyAvalue, propertyBvalue, propertyCvalue];
```

where the values at the end are the values you want the various properties to be equal to.