# Problem with one-to-many NSPredicate in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, core-data

Lets say I have a core data model like this one:

**Item**
attributes:
*name*
*type*
relationships:
*properties*

**Property**
attributes:
*name*
*value*
realationships:
*item*

Each Property is connected to one Item, and each Item many properties. One Property may look exactly the same as another.

I know the value of one Property and want to get the value of another Property from the same Items. So first i fetch all Properties with that value.

```
    NSEntityDescription *propEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Property" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *propPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like 'someName' AND value like %@", value];          
    NSFetchRequest *propRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [propRequest setEntity:propEntity];
    [propRequest setPredicate:propPredicate];  
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray* properties = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:propRequest error:&error];
```

This works fine and I get the expected number of objects in my array. So now I want to fetch all the items that has these properties:

```
    NSEntityDescription *itemEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *itemPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type like %@ AND ANY properties in %@", @"typeValue", properties];          
    NSFetchRequest *itemRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [itemRequest setEntity:itemEntity];
    [itemRequest setPredicate:itemPredicate];

    NSArray* items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:itemRequest error:&error];
```

This also works and I get the expected number of objects in the array. Now I have my items I want to have the values of a property with another name in these items and it's here I encounter my problem:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Property" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like 'someOtherName' AND ANY item in %@", items];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                                                            managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                                                                            sectionNameKeyPath:@"value"
                                                                                            cacheName:@"Props"];
```

Now the FetchedResultsController's fetchedObjects array includes all of the properties with someOtherName not just only the ones that has an item that is in the items array.

Have I missed something here? I have tried using

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like 'someOtherName' AND item in %@", items];
```

and

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like 'someOtherName' AND ALL item in %@", items];
```

but with the same result.

Why don't I get just the properties that has item in items?

If it helps, I have the sql-query that would give the result I'm looking for:

```
Select distinct Property.value from Property where Property.name = 'someOtherName' and property.item in (Select Property.item from Property where Property.name = 'someName' and Property.value = 'someValueIGetFromTheUI')
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your post is not clear. Please explain exactly what do you want to achieve by editing your answer and adding all of the missing details: the relationship from Item to Property is one to many, but what about the inverse relation? Is it one to one or one to many? What exactly are "mediaItem" and "medias" in your example? Are you trying to fetch all of the Property objects with a specific name and related to a specific Item object through the "item" relationship of the Property entity? Or something else?

Comment: I concurre with unforgiven, the question is not clear and the attribute names seem to change from those given.

Comment: I'm sorry, seem to have screwed up in my quest to making my question more general and not just copy-pasting my code. Going to to some editing now.

Comment: Done with the editing. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674055/how-can-i-use-nspredicate-to-filter-on-core-data-relationships

Comment: I believe you need to use a SUBQUERY. Will play with this later

Comment: I have looked at SUBQUERY and I don't understand the syntax. Could anyone give me an example? I have also edited my question with a SQL-query that would work on the underlaying database. (I saved the app-data and queried the sqlite-database in Firefox SQLite Manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your SQL query

```
/*

SELECT DISTINCT Property.value 
FROM Property 
WHERE Property.name = 'someOtherName' 
AND Property.item IN (SELECT Property.item from Property where Property.name = 'someName' 
                      AND Property.value = 'someValueIGetFromTheUI')
*/
```

Translated to a Predicate for a fetch to use in your FRC

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == 'someOtherName' AND SUBQUERY(items, $item, $item.name == 'someName' AND $item.value == %@)", value];



NSEntityDescription *propEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Property" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[fetchRequest setEntity:propEntity];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; // from above

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"value" cacheName:@"Props"];
```

Comment: I feel at bit thick but I'm still confused about the SUBQUERY, what is what in there? Where does items come from? Maybe I can blame it on Monday morning...

Comment: I'm most confused by item.value. the Items don't have a value, the Properties do.

Comment: As per the post that I linked to in a comment, SUBQUERY syntax is: `SUBQUERY(collection, $individualCollectionItem, expression-with-collection-item)`